# How to set the year of a Calendar control based on the value in a TextBox

Tags: c#

I have a calendar control, and want to set the year property of the calendar based on the value in the textbox when the button is clicked.

Comment: I know this is your first question here at SO, but you will need to propose a clear question with a bit more details if you want quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

WPF Application, Calendar control:

```
calendar1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.Year = int.Parse(TextBox.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the WinForms MonthCalendar control:

```
DateTime currentDate = myCalendar.SelectionStart;
currentDate = new DateTime (Int32.Parse(txtYear.Text), currentDate.Month, currentDate.Day);
myCalendar.SelectionStart = currentDate;
```